# How to add footer to bottom in Django

Tags: html, django, web, jinja2, footer

How can I keep my footer at bottom in Django  template
In jinja format I have added content in blocks
The following code:

```
<div class="ui container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock content %}
    </div>
      {% block scripts %}
      {% endblock scripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src={% static 'main.js' %}></script>
    <br>
    <br>
    {% include 'main/footer.html' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I have created a different footer page whenever the content gets over footer appears therefore thefooter lies on top sometimes if small content is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your footer css `footer{margin-bottom:0px !important;}`
or you can do like this you can put your `footer.html` inside a `div` block and give class to it  footer and add css `.footer{margin-bottom:0px !important;}`